# AllowHtml Form Handling: Nothing being written to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, summernote

In an ASP.net MVC 5 application, I'm using Summernote.js to display an HTML text editor for users to input a message. My model includes the necessary attribute:

```
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Welcome Message")]
    public string message { get; set; }
```

My controller binds all the fields to an object and writes them to the database:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,name,surveytype,industryId,start,end,message,resultsdate,resultsfile,resultsfile2")] Survey survey, HttpPostedFileBase bentemplate, HttpPostedFileBase comptemplate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {



            if(bentemplate != null && bentemplate.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var filename = Path.GetFileName(bentemplate.FileName);
                var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/templates"), filename);
                bentemplate.SaveAs(fullpath);
                survey.bentemplateaddress = fullpath;
            }


            if (comptemplate != null && comptemplate.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var filename = Path.GetFileName(comptemplate.FileName);
                var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/templates"), filename);
                bentemplate.SaveAs(fullpath);
                survey.comptemplateaddress = fullpath;
            }

            db.surveys.Add(survey);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(survey);
    }
```

Relevant view code (the textarea-editor class make it appear as a Summernote editor):

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg textarea-editor" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Unfortunately, everything is being written except the welcome message.

Any suggestions on what is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: When debugging, do you see a value in that parameter? If not, does either your browser's devtools or something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) show that you're actually posting a value?

Comment: Yes, when using DevTools, the value is there when I disable SummerNote (and just use plain text) and blank when I enable SummerNote.

Comment: And how are you using Summernote.js? If you're using the [Click to edit](https://summernote.org/examples/#click-to-edit) example, that's not bound to a form field, so your message value won't be included in the POST values.

Comment: I'm including it as a script and using the CSS tag textarea-editor to make it appear. I've added the view implementation above.